Deploying pods to second cluster
I'm new to GKE and currently exploring the cluster. My problem is I have two clusters set up Cluster 1 and Cluster 2. Every time I try to deploy pods using my pod.yaml file, the pods always end up being deployed to Cluster 1, even though I want them in Cluster 2. I checked my kubectl configuration, but can't figure out how to deploy it in Cluster 2.
Here's my current pod.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    app: my-app
    environment: production
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
      limits:
        memory: "512Mi"
        cpu: "1"
    env:
      - name: NGINX_HOST
        value: "localhost"
      - name: NGINX_PORT
        value: "80"
    volumeMounts:
      - name: nginx-volume
        mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 80
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /readiness
        port: 80
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
  - name: redis-container
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - containerPort: 6379
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
    volumeMounts:
      - name: redis-volume
        mountPath: /data
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-volume
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: redis-volume
      emptyDir: {}
  restartPolicy: Always

Do I need to modify the kubectl context, or is there something else I should be doing to specify the cluster in my deployment?
Thanks in advance for your help.
I deploy my pod.yaml using
kubectl apply -f pod.yaml


Your instinct regarding contexts is correct.
The pod.yaml only defines the pod. You can't use this to target a specific context, which does imply the cluster.
Use kubectl config get-contexts to see what contexts you have. The one with a * in the CURRENT column is the cluster you are targeting with kubectl commands.
Use --cluster=CLUSTER_NAME in your kubectl commands to target a specific cluster.
Use kubectl config use-context <context name> to change the default context without having to specify it in every command.
Tools like kubectx will make displaying and switching contexts easier. See here
GKE provides guidance here more specific to GKE, including how to add contexts for GKE clusters.
Bonus advice: In deployment scripts, make sure you are targeting the correct cluster by being explicit.
